# how to count the occurences of a value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, histogram

How to count the number of occurences for a histogram using dataframes

```
d = {'color': ["blue", "green", "yellow", "red, blue", "green, yellow", "yellow, red, blue"],}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How do you go from

| color |
| --- |
| blue |
| green |
| yellow |
| red, blue |
| green, yellow |
| yellow, red, blue |

to

| color | occurance |
| --- | --- |
| blue | 3 |
| green | 2 |
| yellow | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by regex `,s\*` for comma with zero or more whitespaces, then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) into rows and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get the count of values:

```
s = (
    df['color'].str.split(r',\s*')
        .explode()
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('color')
        .reset_index(name='occurance')
)
```

Or can `split` and expand then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = (
    df['color'].str.split(r',\s*', expand=True)
        .stack()
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('color')
        .reset_index(name='occurance')
)
```

`s`:

```
    color  occurance
0    blue          3
1  yellow          3
2   green          2
3     red          2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `.str.get_dummies()`

```
df['color'].str.get_dummies(sep=', ').sum()
```